# ODP.NET + CLOB = ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle10g, odp.net-managed

I'm in trouble try to insert or update some object into my table with CLOB column. 
The update command is this:

```
UPDATE TABELA SET descricao=:descricao,icone=:icone,codigo=:codigo WHERE Id = 2
```

The CLOB column is icone that is an image serialized and store as String64. 
I tried to put only 'test' on icone and it insert successful. 
Then i put the image that a want to store, that is this string:

```
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
```

And its fails.

Then a tested with another image witch his serialization is:

```
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
```

and it works.

What a hell the first image serialization string cannot be inserted?

I'm using Oracle.ManagedDataAccess v4.121.2.0, .NET Framework 4.5.1. and Oracle 10g under Windows 7 x64.

EDIT:
So, i copy the first image serialization string and open PL/SQL and paste into my clob column and this works. I know, it isn't the solution, but i don't think is the DB, so, can be the data provider?

Comment: [This may be relevant](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3649551)? Suggests this might be bug 20361140. Maybe.

Comment: Yes, i think it was. I did some suggestions and put my parameter Direction as OutputInput and it works. Thanks a lot @AlexPoole!

Comment: It might be helpful if you can write up what the problem is and how you worked around it as answer; then anyone else with the same issue will have some steps to follow, without having to go to an outside link. (I don't have enough knowledge of that area to write something coherent *8-)